# Today-widget extension error: Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to install the package react-native-today-widget in version 0.6.4 because of the react-native version of my project (0.44.3), i was able to install the package successfully:

```
yarn add react-native-today-widget@0.6.4
yarn add v0.24.5
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "react-native-today-widget@0.6.4" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.0.0-alpha.6".
warning "react-native-today-widget@0.6.4" has unmet peer dependency "react-native@^0.44.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
└─ react-native-today-widget@0.6.4
✨  Done in 2.62s.
```

After installing the package, I also ran the `react-native link` successfully, but when I run the application build with `react-native run-ios`, I get the following error:

```
error: Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier.


        Embedded Binary Bundle Identifier:  .TodayWidgetExtension
        Parent App Bundle Identifier:       org.reactjs.native.example.testTodayWidget



** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    ValidateEmbeddedBinary build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testTodayWidget.app/PlugIns/TodayWidgetExtension.appex
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testTodayWidget.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to set plugin placeholders for org.reactjs.native.example.testTodayWidget
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.testTodayWidget
```

Did anyone had this error? Any suggestions for a solution or workaround?

Tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem, I run

`./node_modules/.bin/bundle-id org.reactjs.native.example.ProjectName.TodayWidgetExtension`

in the project root, because the project bundle has to be set for the widget project and it has to start with Bundle ID of the main app (containing the widget).

This library runs the [script to set Bundle ID](https://github.com/matejkriz/react-native-today-widget/blob/master/bin/setBundleId.rb) for the widget project [automatically after installation](https://github.com/matejkriz/react-native-today-widget/blob/master/package.json#L24).